# Running mean in production server?

Tags: mean-stack

I am building a mean application for my first time and i was curious how does one actually run this application in a production environment.  Steps would be fantastic. I will test on my vagrant box. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First run `grunt build` to minify files then
`NODE_ENV="production" node server.js`.